# TV series about the world in perpetual darkness and every day a white flare appears in the sky

Tags: story-identification

The premise of the show is a world where the sky is completely black. Every day a flare would come out from the horizon illuminating the town, then dissipating after. The survivors try to locate where the flare comes from.
I remember only being able to watch this on my computer and it wasn't on YouTube. It was so long ago, and I can't really remember much else.

Comment: When did you watch this approximately, and did you have any sense of how old it was? What language was it in? Was it animated or live action?